# Global variable that is accessible in models without passing any information from controller

Tags: zend-framework2

I know how we can declare global variable in config file and then access through

```
Service Locator
```

Currently I am getting this **Global variable** in controller with the help of **service locator** and then pass it to models while creating object.

**Question:** Is it possible that I can get the Global variable in model directly rather than passing in all the models through controller?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes it is possible to get the variable declared in global file into model directly. Instead of declaring it as variable, just define it as constant in the global file so that you can access that variable easily in any models.

```
define('VAR_NAME',Value);
```

and access the variable using.

```
constant('VAR_NAME');
```

Hope it helps
Thanks